# @Import fails to aggregate annotated config from dependent jar

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

I have a project setup where a common module (JPA.jar) containing Spring JPA configuration.

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories({"com.db.jpa.repository"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Jpa {
  // ...
}
```

I intend to invoke the config from a webservice (spring boot) and have a config importing the JPA configuration from JPA.jar.

```
@Configuration
@Import(com.db.config.Jpa.class)
public class JpaApp {
}
```

This fails with following error:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [com/db/config/Jpa.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:180)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:51)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:103)
    at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.createMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:88)
    at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:75)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:81)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.asSourceClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:731)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$SourceClass.getRelated(ConfigurationClassParser.java:1007)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$SourceClass.getAnnotationAttributes(ConfigurationClassParser.java:988)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.collectImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:536)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:509)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:300)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:245)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:635)
    ... 40 more
```

Unable to find any documentation that says this is illegal for Spring's `@Import`. However I see this is done for resources with `@ImportResource`, using a classpath prefix.

I can include a set of configs for each webservice component using the common JPA models and repos, but just wondering if aggregating `@Configuration(s)` specifically using `@Import` from dependency jars is possible.

1. Is it possible?
2. If illegal, is there any rationale to it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Import for configuration classes from other jars. I think that you are getting this error because your jar is not defined as dependency in your pom.xml (if you use maven of course), that's why Spring can't find it.